# How to get a total from All logical Value or an array in PHP

Tags: php

how to get a total from logical or array value

```
I have an asset table
Asset
purchase_date
price
depreciation_age
depreciation_cost_monthly
```

this is the report

```
Asset           Purchase Date     price          depreciation age        depreciation cost/ month         Asset Age         depreciation accumulation
Computer        2016-01-01        10000            40 (month)                   250                        20 (month)              5000
Printer         2016-12-01        50000            36 (month)                   139                        8 (month)               1112
```

This code is to count Asset Age

```
    <?php $date = date("Y-m-d");
     $timeStart = strtotime($thomas['purchase_date']);
    $timeEnd = strtotime("$date");
    $numMonth = 0 + (date("Y",$timeEnd)-date("Y",$timeStart))*12;
    $numMonth += date("m",$timeEnd)-date("m",$timeStart);

     echo $numMonth;
     ?>
```

This code is to count depreciation accumulation

```
        <?php 
         $one = ($thomas['depreciation_cost_monthly']);
        $two = $numMonth;
        $accumulation = $one * $two;
        echo $accumulation;    
        ?>
```

I need help to sum all of accumulation value, I have the code bellow but it is not working

```
    <?php
    $three = array ($accumulation);
       $total = array_sum ($three);
    Echo $total;  ?>
```

Comment: Show the result array of accumulation with its format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `$accumulation` value in your `$three` variable like below

```
<?php 
$one = ($thomas['depreciation_cost_monthly']);
$two = $numMonth;
$accumulation = $one * $two;
echo $accumulation;
$three[] = $accumulation;
?>
```

and sum `$three` array to get total

```
<?php echo array_sum($three); ?>
```